# Infinite loop with a button click

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm asked to create a traffic light, where each button press switches to the next light. I can't figure out how to achieve an infinite loop.

I know there's a really efficient way to do this, but my code is just to give an idea of my desired result.

```js
button.onclick = function () {
    red.style.display = "block";
    yellow.style.display = "none";
    green.style.display = "none"
    button.onclick = function () {
        red.style.display = "none";
        yellow.style.display = "block";
        green.style.display = "none"
        button.onclick = function () {
            red.style.display = "none"
            yellow.style.display = "none";
            green.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (true)`. Is a basic loop, or loop while something is `<= a variable`.

Comment: you should post your full code if possible.

Comment: Please check out this example: https://codepen.io/nevan/pen/GgMXEm

Comment: [Many, many examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+traffic+light+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan - I really wish I could (meaningfully) upvote the effort people make finding duplicates. :-) *(No idea where my brain was actually posting an answer.)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My comment about 3 lights was because you had ONE colour you changed and not THREE lights changing between default and red or green or yellow

Comment: @mplungjan - Ah, I see. The point was to show logic, not UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using static definitions, you can create an array with your elements and keep track of the currently shown one by using the index of it within the array, then when the button is clicked, iterate to the next index and hide the previous one.

```js
let current = 0;

const lights = [
    document.getElementById("red"),
    document.getElementById("orange"),
    document.getElementById("green")
];

const button = document.getElementById("iterate");

button.onclick = function() {
    lights[current].style.display = "none";
  
  current++;
  
  if(current == lights.length)
    current = 0;
    
    lights[current].style.display = "block";
};
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
  
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#red {
  display: block;
  
  background: red;  
}

#orange {
  background: orange;  
}

#green {
  background: green;  
}
```

```html
<button id="iterate">Iterate</button>

<div id="red"></div>
<div id="orange"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

Comment: You need 3 lights

Answer (score 0):

```
currentActive = 1 //value should be 1 /2 / 3 and make sure this is a global variable
setTimeout(() => {
  // make sure red, yellow and green variable is properly defined here, 
  // call this after defining these variables by document.getElementById() 
  red.style.display = currentActive == 1 ? "block" : 'none';
  yellow.style.display = currentActive == 2 ? "block" : 'none';
  green.style.display = currentActive == 3 ? "block" : 'none';

  currentActive++; //increase for the next to occour
  currentActive = currentActive % 3; // mod by 3 so to run between 1,2,3
}, 1000)

//here using 1000 milisecond use your desire time as delay
```

Comment: If you make a snippet, make a [mcve]